# update body style from click event in component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a button which has a clickEvent.  I wan't to add an inline style to the html body tag when this button is clicked.  I want to remove the style when the button is clicked again.  I have the methods already to handle state changes for click event.  I just need to know the correct "react" way to update the style on the body tag to add/remove overflow-y: hidden

```
handleConfigurationDrawerToggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        configurationDrawerOpen: !prevState.configurationDrawerOpen
    }))
}

<div 
    className={configurationDrawerModalClasses}
    onClick={this.handleConfigurationDrawerToggle} />
```

Comment: Please post the code for the whole component. What is happening in your click handler? What element are you trying to update? More code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook to handle the toggle anytime your state changes:

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextState.configurationDrawerOpen) {
        document.querySelector('body').style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('body').style.overflowY = 'auto';
    }
}
```

Comment: @johnsontroye Updated answer

Comment: @johnsontroye Updated again with the "react" way

Comment: I'm wondering if this kind of logic should be in a separate component that is only concerned with updating the body.  Thoughts??

Comment: Hmm, yeah it depends on how you want to trigger the updates. You can make an HOC that you can wrap your components in that passes in an `updateBody` function as a prop. If you do it that way though, you have to manually trigger the body updates. Doing it this way in the same components gets you that automatic toggling which is nice. But, if you are going to need that toggle functionality a bunch of places in the app, then yeah abstracting that piece would be a smart thing to do.

Comment: agree.  thanks for circling back and sharing your thoughts on that.